# Having rails compatibility issues on my system. how do i wipe rails and start over?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, ubuntu

I have rails 3.2.6 on my kubuntu system (13.04).
I had rails 3.2.6 and rails 4.0.0 on my system.
I uninstalled rails 4.0.0 and then ran into all kinds of issues with rails not working right since then (my job only uses rails 3.2.X).

When I do a gem list, it says rails (3.2.6). However, when I do a rails -v it reports rails 4.0.0.

How can I completely wipe rails and start over fresh??

thanks!!

ironmantis7x

Comment: Have you installed rvm?

Comment: yes and it is not acting right ...

Comment: create gemsets with vim to start from 'scratch'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the best way, but it could get you close to removing rails 4.

If it rails 4 was installed by apt, you could get apt to remove it.

First comfirm rails 4 was installed by the package manager:

Run `which rails` and see where the rails command lives. 
Then run `dpkg -L rails` which will list all the files installed with apt for the package rails.

You could of course do this in one line

```
dpkg -L rails | grep `which rails`
```

Then if your result from which matches, then remove this using apt.

`apt-get --purge remove rails`

Hope this helps,

Will